# why can't vampires and werewolves be together

Tags: low-fantasy

People are always writing stories about how werewolves and vampires can't be together, but why though? they may not like each other, but what if a wolf and a vampire were to find love one day. wouldn't that be okay though. I am writing about a wolf and a vampire, but all i get is negative feedback about how the two can't be together, why can't the be a couple.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a worldbuilding question, but the main reason that they haven't traditionally been together is because people have terible imagination and just copy pre-existing background fluff. You should please yourself, and you'll do everyone a favour if you're successful.

Comment: The Underworld movies are an example that addresses all of these topics.  That said, there are so many lore variants on both races that there are too many ways this could be answered; as such, any answers would be primarily opinion based.  We'd need to know more about how YOU define werewolf and vampire society or atleast what sources you are pulling from to help you refine it further.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. While we can address plot-related issues stemming from a need to maintain consistency with the rules of your world as you have already developed them, doing that development for you is outside the scope of this community. There is nothing wrong with a vampire/werewolf relationship you are writing _unless your world's societies define it so_. As such, I am voting to close this question as _too story-based_.

Comment: Because they are from geographically different regions.  I can't create an answer because this is on hold but historically, Different cities had different monster myths.  Bram Stoker took a bunch of these and called them Vampire.  Another bunch of them got lumped together to be werewolves.  They are at each other's throats because Universal Pictures decided to cash in on two of it's monster movie series and have their werewolf fight Dracula.  The funniest thing about that is that the movie never got made.  Yet it still made its way into our cultural consciousness.

Answer (score 1):

Most books have some kind of a conflict in them. It became a tradition to have Vampires and werewolves fight each other, and map social conflict into them. E.g. Vampires represent snobbish elites, werewolves -- uneducated savages. Or vampires=goths/hipsters and werevolves=jocks/rednecks.

You can have write a Romeo&Juliet kind of story where the love thrives despite social barriers.